# How to stop HTTPBuilder from parsing specific content types like application/json

Tags: http, groovy

I am using a groovy `HTTPBuilder` for a very generic api which not only deals with json. Therefor I want to controll how the response is deserialized on my own. However it seems that the response handler is always parsing the content type `application/json` into a map. How can I just get the plain text (or byte[])?

```
        def lambda = new HTTPBuilder(lambdaUrl)
        lambda.request(method) {
            send contentType, payload

            response.success = { resp, reader ->
                if (log.isDebugEnabled())log.debug("response: $resp")
                lambdaResponseStatus = resp.statusLine.statusCode
                lambdaResponse = Reader.isAssignableFrom(reader.getClass()) ? reader.text : reader.toString()
            }
        }
```

Note that `reader.toString()` is basically invoking a toString on a LinkedHashMap. But what I actually want is just the plain reader whatever content type I get in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this has some unwanted side effects but in the end the solution was as easy as passing the wanted content type as part of the request.

```
lambda.request(method, ContentType.BINARY)
...
response.success = { resp, reader -> reader.bytes }
```